# Realm for SharePoint Claims based auth

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth

I have a SharePoint web site that use an Issuer Provider for SAML. When I create a new SharePoint Web Application the /_trust folder is created in IIS. So, I guess that `/_trust/default.aspx` could be used for Claims processing. But when I post form with Claims to /_trust I receive 401 or 403 error. What is a correct realm for SharePoint?

Currently I use `http://<sharepoint>/_trust`

Comment: Just check the wctx attribute , the _layouts/Authenticate.aspx page might be failing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have run the powershell scripts correctly and trust is created between Sharepoint and IP .
I think the redirection should be done in a proper way:

```
Response.Redirect("default.aspx?" + "wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=" + "https://www.xyz.com/_trust/default.aspx" +"&wctx=" +"https://www.xyz.com/" + "/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F");
```

OR if there is trust issue.

403 _ forbidden error it means the user doesnt have permissions/access to the sharepoint site.(Check the STS certificate permissions as well)

Please refer the link on configuring trusted providers : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You specify the realm when you configure the Identity Provider.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607753.aspx

Comment: Is it required to have ADFS installed?

Comment: No. Any SAML IdP will work.